# Regular Expression Range not working as intended for verifying randomly generated passwords

Tags: regex, c++11

I am trying to verify passwords generated using a random password generator function by using regular expression in C++.

**the rules for the passwords are:**
The password has to be 8 letters total length. the password can be 4 capital alphabets and 4 numbers or 6 capital alphabets and 2 numbers.

**Valid Examples:**

- ABCD1234
- PQRSTU88

I am using this **expression**:
/^(?=.{8}$)([A-Z]{4,6})([0-9]{2,4})\w+/gm

and this **website** to test the expression:
http://regexr.com/3frd4

it works when the range is kept as **{1,4}** but if I change the range to **{2,4}** the second example password fails.

Clicking on the details button shows that for the first example password: ABCD1234,

Capturing Group #1 captures ABCD & Capturing Group #2 captures only 123 (not 1234?).

For the second example password: PQRSTU88,

Capturing Group #1 captures PQRSTU & Capturing Group #2 captures only 8 (not 88?).

from what I understand {2,4} specifies at least 2 numbers to at most 4 numbers. Then why is my regex not working for that range in case of the second example.

Comment: It is because of `\w+`. Why did you use it?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew I am new to Regular Expression, didn't fully understand the meaning of \w. You are right it works after removing it. If you had posted this comment as a answer I would have marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes, I have posted an answer. And you accepted it, thanks. I also upvoted the question. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second string fails the validation as it contains 5 letters and 2 digits only, but your regex requires at least 1 more word char after them.

> The password has to be 8 letters total length. the password can be 4 capital alphabets and 4 numbers or 6 capital alphabets and 2 numbers.

You need to use

```
^(?:[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}|[A-Z]{6}[0-9]{2})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CoKPAv/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - alternation group start

  - `[A-Z]{4}` - 4 uppercase ASCII letters
  - `[0-9]{4}` - 4 digits (8 all in all)
- `|` - or

  - `[A-Z]{6}` - 6  uppercase ASCII letters
  - `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits (8 all in all)
- `)` - end of an alternation group
- `$` - end of string.